# Trying to create a custom Panel with ExtJS

Tags: extjs, panel

Can't find out why its isn't working.. 
 I'm trying create a custom panel for multiple uses. 
Is it the way? Or am i totally wrong.

I'm a beginner in ExtJS, so i'll be happy to a little explain..
thanks
(i'm trying to run this code on the fiddle to see the immediate result - )

```
Ext.application({

    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var custom = Ext.define('Ext.BET', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

    }
});

Ext.define('Ext.BET', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.bet',
    constructor: function (cnfg) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.initConfig(cnfg);
    },
    config: {
        collapsible: true,
        frame: true,
        bodyStyle: 'background-color: #FFFFFF',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            textarea: focus,
            id: 'tbx'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            id: 'btn'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            id: 'search'
        }]

    },
    afterRender: function () {
        var btn = Ext.getCmp('btn');
        var tbx = Ext.getCmp('tbx');
        var btn2 = Ext.getCmp('search');
        var totalWidth = btn2.getWidth() + btn.getWidth() + tbx.getWidth();
        this.setWidth(totalWidth);
    },
    onRender: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: You want to run this on fiddle ? Means should we correct this code or what you want ?

Comment: i'm running this code  on: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor
just to see if its work.

but i gonna use it elsewhere

just to explain the :
  "name: 'Fiddle',"

Comment: You should not use ext.define instead use ext.create.But then its breaking in afterrender event ..checking this thing , will update fiddle once it fix it.

Comment: thank you very much! i was stuck on this a lot..

Comment: yes, you should..

Comment: I have updated my answer in fiddle.Its working fully functional as you want.

Comment: i cant upvote your answer because i am a new user...

Comment: Yes I forgot sorry. But did you understood changes made by me

Comment: yes, and now its work perfectly thanks to you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Ext.create instead of Ext.define.Refer this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1s6u&view/editor).